# Puppeteer page doesn't want to load totally in headless mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium, headless

Here is my code:

```js
// Open the browser
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ["--no-sandbox"]
});
let page = await browser.newPage();

navPromise = page.waitForSelector('#js_boite_reception').then(() => {
    console.log('received');
});
await page.goto(entMessagesURL);
await navPromise;

// Wait 10 seconds, to be sure that is not because my connection is slow (it's not)
logger.log(`On the messages page (session=${username})`);
await delay(10000);

// Write an html file with the page content
let pageContent = await page.content();
require('fs').writeFileSync('./test.html', pageContent);
```

The `received` is not displayed and I'm getting a timeout error. But, if I remove the waitForSelector function, and I only write the `test.html` file, we can see that:

### Headless mode enabled, a part of the page is not loaded

[image: headless mode en]

### Headless mode disabled, all the page is loaded

[image: Headless mode dis]

With headless mode, only a part of the page content is loaded. I don't know why. Even if I add a timeout of one minute, it won't load more... What can I do?

Note: I tried with a useragent:

```js
await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36");
```

(under the `let page = await browser.newPage()`)

Comment: if your trying for a live website  , in the headless mode you dont have some headers in your request (user agent most notably ) so some websites would block the request as they figure out its a bot sending the request ... so try adding user agent header to your page before sending the request `page.setUserAgent` .... if this is a website on your localhost you may need to check the console for some js error

Comment: I have the same problem, even with a useragent...

Comment: Try check console logs. See https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#debugging-tips

Comment: There is nothing in the console, and adding a slowmode doesn't fix anything... :\

Comment: some websites do more than just checking user-agents to detect headless mode. have you tried https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth#readme?

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything. But I think the website is not blocking me, but the page doesn't want to load totally in headless mode

Comment: Have you tried "page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })" instead of using waitForSelector?

Comment: Yes, I tried. And it didn't work

Comment: @Androz2091can you try goto with option waitUntil, "await page.goto(entMessagesURL, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
 "

Comment: I also think about `waitUntil` https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.17.0&show=api-pagegotourl-options

Comment: it didn't work...

Comment: have you been able to figure out what was the problem? I have similar issue and suspect that the javascript is not executed to load the missing pieces on the page

Comment: Yes @grafbumsdi, it's now working. Here is my fixed code: https://github.com/Androz2091/pronote-bot/blob/master/pronote/fetchMessage.js. Sorry, I couldn't remember how I fixed it, but this code works.

Answer (score 12):

```
await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36");
```

This worked for me! My website was blocking headless mode when tried it locally. After adding the header, I was finally able to find the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure its a condition race and it is happening because you are trying to get the selector before you go to the page.

Try to move those lines:

```js
await page.goto(entMessagesURL);
navPromise = page.waitForSelector('#js_boite_reception').then(() => {
    console.log('received');
});
```

I cant try reproduce your error because i dont know what page is and the language that it had been writted

Comment: No, look at the screenshots. The page isn't loaded totally :\

Answer (score 1):

You can try with an option [waitUntil](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options)

```
await page.goto(entMessagesURL, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had no problems on a login page, but the home page was broken (half loaded) in a headless mode.
(puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth plugin is also active)

In my case this helped:

1. In any normal browser rob headers from request, I took the first request after submit/sing_up button was pressed
2. Add all/some robbed headers before you do anything (before moving to target page):

```
await page.setUserAgent('......................');
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
  'Accept-Language': '.....................',
  'Cache-Control':'.....................',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
  'sec-ch-ua': '.....................',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
});
```

3. Try it, if no result yet - delete/add some headers and retry (I had 9 more headers in original request)